# How can i use <=< operator from a monad when i want to apply the composition of function in haskell(using monads)?

Tags: haskell, monads

i am new to haskell language. i've just started using monads and o simply cannot figure out how it works. i try to call `<=<` from Maybe monad like this : `(\x->Just (x+1)) <=< (\y -> Just (y *2)) $8` expecting the result `Just 17`. but it shows the error :

```
<interactive>:45:19: error:
    * Variable not in scope:
        (<=>)
          :: (Integer -> Maybe Integer)
             -> (Integer -> Maybe Integer) -> Integer -> t
    * Perhaps you meant one of these:
        `<>' (imported from Prelude), `<*>' (imported from Prelude),
        `<=' (imported from Prelude)
```

This is the code:

```
(<=<) :: (a -> Maybe b) -> (c -> Maybe a) -> c -> Maybe b

f <=< g = (\ x -> g x >>= f)
```

Comment: You made a typo: it is `<=<`, not `<=>`.

Comment: yes, that was the mistake . thank you

Answer (score 3):

That operator is not available in the `Prelude`, you need to import it from `Control.Monad`. For example, add this to the top of your file:

```
import Control.Monad ((<=<))
```